# Azure media service 4k Video

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

Is it possible to encode videos with a 4K Resolution output?

I assumed it would be a case of changing the  but this just results in job error?

What are the limits if this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just added 4K transcoding capbility: please read details here:http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/05/introducing-premium-encoding-in-azure-media-services/. And you can check on the implementation details here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/03/06/how-to-use-premium-encoding-in-azure-media-services/.